# How does WordPress editor preserve formatting of text when copy and pasted?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce, editor

I noticed when we copy and paste something from some other place to WordPress editor then it preserves its original form. The data pasted isn't simply some text but HTML and CSS as well. How does WordPress do it? May I have an example of code or reference to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume (I haven't looked) that they respond to the [`paste` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event) and use the [`getData` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/getData) of the [`clipboardData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData) property of the [`ClipboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent) object, asking it for formatted text (probably passing `"text/html"` for the format parameter). Then they take the resulting HTML and include it in the editor.

For example: If you copy the text of the paragraph above to the clipboard, then run this snippet and click anywhere in the body of the snippet and press the paste keyboard shortcut on your system (Ctrl+V etc.), it should show the *formatted* text from your clipboard:

```js
document.addEventListener("paste", function(e) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =
      (e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData("text/html")) || "";
});
```

```html
<div>Click here to focus the window, then do a paste</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

They probably fall back to `"text/plain"` if they don't get anything for `"text/html"`:

```js
document.addEventListener("paste", function(e) {
    if (e.clipboardData) {
        var output = document.getElementById("output");
        var str = e.clipboardData.getData("text/html");
        if (str) {
            console.log("html");
            output.innerHTML = str;
        } else {
            console.log("plain text");
            str = e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
            output.textContent = str;
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div>Click here to focus the window, then do a paste</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, That was really helpful.